# JQUERY, TEXTAREA, HEIGHT

Tags: jquery, height, textarea

I have looked through all the Q&A about this topic but could not find an answer.
I want to set the height of a JQUERY textarea to 200px or 100% of the container.
See:

http://jsfiddle.net/timodenhartog/q56MZ/2/

I have tried:

```
$('basic').css('height', '100%');       
$('basic').css('height', '200px');
```

Can anyone assist me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to your markup, `basic` is the ID of `<input>` element, so your selector should start with `#`:

```
$('#basic').css('height', '100%');
```

**REF:** http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/q56MZ/3/

```
$('#basic').height('100%');
```